# Illegal call of non-static member function

Tags: c++, function, call, non-static

I wish to make a calculator that can calculate numbers of almost any length.

The first function that I needed is one that converts a string into a linked list and then returns a pointer to the head of the list.

However, when compiling I am faced with an error:
error C2352: 'main::StringToList' : illegal call of non-static member. Line: 7;

I provide you with my main.cpp and main.h files.

Thanks for any

### main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
main::node *head = main::StringToList("123");

main::node *temp = new main::node;

temp = head;
while (temp->next != NULL)
{
    cout << temp->data;
    temp = temp->next;
}

std::cout << "\nThe program has completed successfully\n\n";
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

main::node * StringToList(string number) 
{

int loopTimes = number.length() - 1; 
int looper = 0;         
int *i = new int;       
i = &looper;            
main::node *temp = new main::node;  
main::node *head;               
head = temp;            
for ( i = &loopTimes ; *i >= 0; *i = *i - 1) 
{
    temp->data = number[*i] - 48;   
    main::node *temp2 = new main::node;         
    temp->next = temp2;             
    temp = temp2;                   
}
temp->next = NULL;                  
return head;
}
```

### main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class main
{
public:
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
node* StringToList (string number);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Naming your class "main" is really confusing.

Comment: `int *i = new int; i = &looper;` Why do you create a new integer and then immediately throw away the pointer to it so that it becomes lost forever?

Answer (score 2):

You need to instanciate your main class and call StringToList as member:

```
main* m = new main;
main::node *head = m->StringToList("123");
...
delete m;
```

Comment: Even if it does make sense for the function to be non-static (which it probably doesn't), there's no reason to create the object with `new`, and definitely no reason to leak it like that.

Comment: I definitely agree to that - there are a lot more problems with the source code shown above, be it variable naming, indentation or whatsoever, but the primary reason for the compiler error was calling a method as a static, so you either have to define it as static or call it as a member :-) (and of course clean up afterwards)

Comment: In which case, create a temporary or automatic object. There's absolutely no reason for dynamic allocation here, even if you do remember to clean up. (Although a temporary would be problematic, since `main()` would be interpreted as a function call).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare `StringToList` as `static` for this to work:

```
static node* StringToList(string number);
```

In this line:

```
main::node *head = main::StringToList("123");
```

You are trying to call `StringToList` without having first created an object of type `main`. Since it is a non-static member-function, this does not work. You'd have to do it like this:

```
main foo;
main::node *head foo.StringToList("123");
```

Which does not really make sense for your usecase, though.

Comment: It will work, but shouldn't the OP create a constructor instead?

Comment: Well, the OPs code is a bit problematic. For classical linked list it makes sense to have a `node`-class and a separate function to construct the list. If you would do it in the constructor of the `node`-class, you'd get a recursive constructor-call, which might be confusing.

Comment: @Anonymous: Of course it can. If there were any non-static members then it couldn't access those, but there aren't any. (Of course, that makes the existence of the class itself rather pointless, but criticising the design is somewhat off-topic).

Comment: @Anonymous: `node` is a public nested type, and therefore can be accessed from any non-member function.

Answer (score 0):

Since `node* StringToList (string number);` is not static so you can't call it as `main::StringToList("123");`

Make an object of main first then call it like

```
main mn;
mn.StringToList("123");
```

Otherwise declare `node* StringToList (string number);` as `static node* StringToList (string number);`

Comment: It makes more sense to make `StringToList` a static member function rather than creating an instance of a class.

Comment: And it makes even more sense to get rid of the class and put the function in a namespace, unless there's some non-static data, virtual functions, or whatever that were omitted from the question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:- Was thinking to write the same, but industrial C# effect just confused me.So thought better Pollex can confirm.